# value type variable and reference type variable

Tags: c#

I am having a hard time understanding this.

If we pass `variable by reference` the method we are calling   can change the **value of the Caller's variable** by changing its paramater value .

My question is

we have two variables

```
       int _myinteger=10;
       object _myobject=null;
```

here `_myinteger` is a value type and `_myobject` is reference type variable ,I want to know how can we pass these variable's by reference and how does it change's the value.? can anyone explain with an simple example.

Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `int` by reference with the `ref` command, and the `object` is already passed by reference. More specifically, the reference to the object is passed by value.

In other words, value types are by default passed by value and reference types are by default passing their reference by value.

Consider this code:

```
public void ByRef(ref int i, object o)
```

<strike>both there are passed by reference.</strike>

**UPDATE:** the community wants to clarify this statement. If you were to change a value on the `object` that is passed it would be changed at the caller. However, if you were to build a new one (e.g. `o = new Object();`) with the aforementioned signature the caller would not change. If you wanted that to work as well you'd need to do this:

```
public void ByRef(ref int i, ref object o)
```

Comment: There is no boxing of a value type when passed by reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: so does it mean Objects are by `default` passed by reference ??

Comment: @Baldrick, very good observation. I should have known that. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Kyle, yes `object` is passed by reference by default.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Also, and it will help when explaining how `ref` works. The reference to the object is passed by value, which is a different way of saying "reference types are passed by reference".

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I was reading a page from skeet's book which classifies the statement `OBJECTS ARE PASSED BY REFERENCE IN C# BY DEFAULT` as a myth

Comment: @Kyle My explanation of "the reference to the object is passed by value" is basically from Skeet's book and is the basis of his myth argument.

Comment: `both there are passed by reference.` is not true

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I'm issuing the `ref` keyword on the `int` and the `object` is *arguably* passed by reference. The point here is that if you change the values in the method they will change the caller's values. You can argue all day on whether or not they are *literally* passed by reference and we will get nowhere.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I'd argue saying no to that. Inside your method if you say `o = new object()` will the actual argument changes?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, actually yes. The callers reference would be updated with a new object.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Are you sure? I'd say **no**.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud No it will *not*. That will only happen if you use the `ref` keyword on the object parameter. I agree with @SriramSakthivel. It is a mistake to say that objects in C# is passed by reference by default since that is not what happens.

Comment: This is the reason for Jon Skeet's explanation. `o = new Object()` is actually re-assigning the callee's local copy of the reference value (hence the caller's copy does not point to this new object), not working on the type it refers to. This is why `ref object o` *does* allow the caller's copy of the reference to be mutated, and hence why `ref object o` actually has a use. The confusion comes in when you think "reference types are passed by reference".

Answer (score 3):

Use [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword, It helps you to pass value by reference.

> The ref keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by
>   value. The effect of passing by reference is that any change to the
>   parameter in the method is reflected in the underlying argument
>   variable in the calling method. The value of a reference parameter is
>   always the same as the value of the underlying argument variable.

```
private void DoSomething(ref int someintByRef)
{
    someintByRef = 4;
}

 int _myinteger=10;
DoSomething(ref _myinteger);
Console.WriteLine(myinteger);//Prints 4
```

**Update:**
To be more clear, I'd say without the use of `ref` "value types" and "reference types" are passed by *value only*. Difference is for "value types" value(complete instance) will be copied and completely new instance is passed in case of reference types "refence of the instance" is **copied** and passed by value.

When we use `ref`, no doubt both are passed by reference

Comment: +1 That was a simple explanation...But why would anyone do that since it changes the variable in the calling method ..should we pass value type variable by reference ??

Answer (score 0):

For reference types:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

void ByRef(ref User user)
{
    user = new User();
}

void ByVal(User user)
{
    user = new User();
}

void Test()
{
    var user = null;
    ByVal(user);
    // user is still null
    ByRef(ref user);
    // user is new User()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are diffrent behavior for the diffrent type of variables. if we talk about value types they are consist about the values only. the don't share memory locations. so every value type have there own values and they can play with it as they want. on the other hand refrence type variables are diffrent in nature they work with sharing mode so if i create an object then the value of this object is being shared by their users. I recomand you to have a look for below video for more clearification.

So if you pass a value type variable to a method the copy of values is being assigned to the using variable. so if you want to use the same variable. then you can have ref keywork for refranceing the value of the same object. on the other side object / refrence type variables are not needed to be ref keyword as they are already refranced by default nature.

Try below code tu understand the behavior.

```
 class Program
    {
        static object reftypedata = "I am Testing. ";
        static int valuetypeData = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CalcValue(valuetypeData);
            CalcValuewithRef(ref valuetypeData);
            Calcobject(reftypedata);


            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static void CalcValue(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value Type.....");
            Console.WriteLine("before Processing i={0}", i);
            i = 100;
            Console.WriteLine("After Processing i={0}", i);
            Console.WriteLine("After Processing valueTypeData = {0}", valuetypeData);

        }
        public static void CalcValuewithRef(ref int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value with Ref Type.....");
            Console.WriteLine("before Processing i={0}", i);
            i = 100;
            Console.WriteLine("After Processing i={0}", i);
            Console.WriteLine("After Processing valueTypeData = {0}", valuetypeData);

        }
        public static void Calcobject(object value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reference Type.....");
            Console.WriteLine("before Processing value={0}", value);
            value = "Default Value Has been Changed.";
            Console.WriteLine("After Processing value={0}", value);
            Console.WriteLine("After Processing reftypedata={0}", reftypedata);


        }
    }
```

Output:

```
    Value Type.....
    before Processing i=10
    After Processing i=100
    After Processing valueTypeData = 10

 Value with Ref Type.....
    before Processing i=10
    After Processing i=100
    After Processing valueTypeData = 100

  Reference Type.....
    before Processing value=I am Testing.
    After Processing value=Default Value Has been Changed.
    After Processing reftypedata=I am Testing.
```

you also can reffer to this [youtube video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CsRK1HzJWk)